# How do I get the first child of an XElement?

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net

The old XmlElement class had a FirstChild property. What is the XElement equivalent?

Visual Studio rejects .Element(), .Elements()[0]., and .Elements().First()

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.linq.xelement.aspx mentions FirstNode(); is this what you are after?

Comment: [Descendants](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb360635.aspx)

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I get the first element after an element with LINQ-to-XML?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1222242/how-can-i-get-the-first-element-after-an-element-with-linq-to-xml)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You want the [`IEnumerable<XElement> Descendants()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb360635.aspx) method of the `XElement` class.

```
XElement element = ...;
XElement firstChild = element.Descendants().First();
```

This sample program:

```
var document = XDocument.Parse(@"
    <A x=""some"">
        <B y=""data"">
            <C/>
        </B>
        <D/>
    </A>
    ");

Console.WriteLine(document.Root.Descendants().First().ToString());
```

Produces this output:

```
<B y="data">
    <C/>
</B>
```

Answer (score 3):

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.linq.xelement.aspx states that XElement has a property `FirstNode`, inherited from `XContainer`. This is described as the first child of the current node, and so is probably what you're after.

Comment: I tried `element.FirstNode`, looking for an `XElement`, but it returned an `XText` object with "\r\n [several spaces]" as the value.

Comment: @jbobbins It's possible that there's been a few changes since that was posted - you are responding to an answer that's celebrating its 6th birthday today.